# mysql_real_escape_string() is not escaping anything

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

1. would I need to use real escape in both my INSERT and SELECT FROM statements?
2. why the syntax I'm using in the following example isn't working (It's just one of the many ways I've tried)?

   ```
   //insert user input for word 1
   $sql = "INSERT INTO test (Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4, Word5)
   VALUES('$Word1','$Word2','$Word3','$Word4','$Word5')",
   mysql_real_escape_string($Word1),
   mysql_real_escape_string($Word2),
   mysql_real_escape_string($Word3),
   mysql_real_escape_string($Word4),
   mysql_real_escape_string($Word5);
   if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend that you avoid escaping altogether, and move directly to [prepared statements](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) with [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), perhaps via [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  It's ultimately simpler and safer:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql =
    'INSERT INTO mytable ' .
    '(Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4, Word5)' .
    'VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$words = array('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5');
$stmt->execute($words);

$words = array('word6', 'word7', 'word8', 'word9', 'word10');
$stmt->execute($words);
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to use [sprintf()](http://us.php.net/sprintf), to do so properly you need to reformat your code a little:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO test (Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4, Word5)
VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
mysql_real_escape_string($Word1),
mysql_real_escape_string($Word2),
mysql_real_escape_string($Word3),
mysql_real_escape_string($Word4),
mysql_real_escape_string($Word5)
);
```

Comment: what is the significance of %s?

Comment: it's a data type specifer for php formatting strings, if you go to php.net/sprintf it will detail the various type specifiers available