# Will mysql_real_escape_string() cancel out stripslashes()?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysql-real-escape-string, stripslashes

I am having users enter some information that will be stored in sql.  Of course I want to escape all the quotation marks and such.. but i don't want that stuff to be outputted into the final html either.

I'm running this function for all $_POST variables.  Is it valid?

```
 function cleanArray($array)  //prevent funky insertions
{
foreach ($array as &$value)
{
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(nl2br($value)));
}
return $array;  
}
```

I'm worried about the escape string and stripslashes cancelling eachother out?

Comment: stripslashes will remove  the slashes from user's input and than mysql_real_escape_string will add them back :) Btw, just a note, mysql_real_eascape could be used only with link identifier OR database connection already opened, otherwise it returns error.

Comment: You could avoid escaping altogether if you use prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357340/mysql-php-mysql-real-escape-syntax-issues/4358177#4358177

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish something very simple.  Escape the quotations.. and then UN-escape them before i output my content.

Comment: @ionfish at which point are you escaping the quotations?

Comment: If you use prepared statements, you don't need to escape or un-escape anything.  See [http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) for a good introduction.

Comment: I'm escaping them right before I'm inserting into mysql.

Comment: `function pruneArray($array)  //clean the crap off the insertions after outputting from mysql

{
$crap = array('\"', "\'");
$clean = array('"', "'");

 foreach ($array as &$pruned)
 {
  $pruned = str_replace($crap, $clean, $pruned);
 }
 return $array;
}`

this is probably ghetto, but works for me.

Answer (score 5):

To escape string data before inserting it into the database, use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

To output the same data later in a HTML page, use `htmlspecialchars()` if you want HTML source code to be displayed as literal characters, or `strip_tags()` if you want to silently remove any HTML.

There is no need for anything else, except if you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) activated, in which case you'd indeed need `stripslashes()` before doing the `mysql_real_escape_string()`. However, magic quotes are [deprecated and it would be much better to turn them off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: will htmlspecialchars turn \' into '  ?

Comment: @ionfish no, but it will turn `'` into `&#039;` if [the ENT_QUOTES parameter](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is set

Comment: i'm just trying to remove all the slashes from the quotations while still protecting my database.  How would i accomplish that.

Comment: @ionfish I don't understand where those slashes come from in the first place?

Comment: i'm inserting data into mysql so lets say someone enters "hello"  it would be stored as /"hello/".  I don't want that to be outputted on my webpage.  So after retrieving it from mysql I want to output it back to "hello"

Comment: `function pruneArray($array)  //clean the crap off the insertions after outputting from mysql`

`{`
`$crap = array('\"', "\'");`
`$clean = array('"', "'");`

 `foreach ($array as &$pruned)`
 `{`
  `$pruned = str_replace($crap, $clean, $pruned);`
 `}`
 `return $array;`
`}`

this is probably ghetto, but works for me.

Comment: @ionfish you probably have magic quotes turned on. If at all possible, try turning them off (see my link above)